# Set panel component div id

Tags: css, html, gwt, panel

I am using a DockLayoutPanel in GWT. I've added a few things to this panel.

I have a DockLayoutPanel.

```
DockLayoutPanel dockpanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
```

I've added an image to "North":

```
Image logo = new Image("imageurl.com");
dockpanel.addNorth(logo, 5);
```

I've added an additional collection of panels as well:

```
dockpanel.add(otherSplitLayoutPanel, 5);
```

I need to apply CSS to the individual frames created by the DockLayoutPanel. Specifically, I need to apply CSS to the "North" frame which contains the image. Basically, I want to set the dimensions of the images such that they will be relative to the size of its container. I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to assign a div ID to this frame so that I can target it with CSS.

I don't want to just apply the CSS to the entire panel, so assigning and using an ID for the DockLayoutPanel is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign ids to set CSS. You can use CSS classes or other selectors instead.

You can set a CSS class on your image:

```
logo.addStyleName("logo");
```

In your CSS:

```
.logo {width: 50%; height: 50%;}
```

Or you can set it directly in your code:

```
logo.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(50, Unit.PCT);
logo.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(50, Unit.PCT);
```